# WordPress Menu Problem: Dropdown Menu Heading Opens Blank Page

Tags: wordpress, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm just getting started with WordPress and I need some help creating a menu. I'm using WordPress 3.1 with the Suffusion theme.

I've got a dropdown menu functioning. I created a category. Let's call it "My Pages". I want to list the pages in my site (not posts) under this category. In the Menu section of WP, I dragged the required pages and placed them under "My Pages". I indented them. I activated the menu. The menu appears, and I can use the dropdown to select the page I want.

The problem is that if I click the heading, "My Pages", then I get "Not Found. Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here." How do I solve this problem? I don't want the menu heading to open its own page. I simply want it to be the heading for the dropdown menu.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: There's a specific StackExchange for Wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/, you'll probably have more success there.

Comment: Town, Thanks you for the message. I didn't know about the WordPress stack exchange site. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

1) In Suffusion Options --> Other Graphical Elements --> Main Navigation Bar --> Pages in Navigation Bar --> "Pages" Title: 
I set it to "My Pages".

2) Pages in Navigation Bar - All or Selected:
Checkmarked Include selections from the next option

3) Select pages to include/exclude in Navigation Bar:
Checkmarked the appropriate pages.

4) Clicked Save Page 'Main Navigation Bar'

5) In order to get the dropdown menu to display the pages in the correct order, edit each page and under Page Attributes input a number under Order. (I thought that Order only affected the horizontal positioning of tabs in the menu. In the dropdown menu it changes the vertical position).